# Bootstrap page scrolls up due to carousel

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I have been searching for a while now not sure why my page scrolls up to the top of the page ( i am using Bootstrap's carousel). 
I doubt if it's related to sizing as I intentionally made all pics of the same size before using them in the carousel. 
I haven't found any satisfying solution and so posting my question here. Below is the codepen link for my problem. Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

here is the site link:
https://codepen.io/Tabitha44/pen/XgWeGW?q=sandra+lee&limit=all&type=type-pens

here is my html code:

```
<div class="container2">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="border:10px solid #f2f2f2;">
     <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
       <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
       <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
       <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

     <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active">
         <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/t4bc0d3/image/upload/v1497010408/Images/Mom_Age_20.jpg" alt="Picture of a 20yr old Sandra Lee" class="photo d-block img-fluid">
          <div class="carousel-caption cap1 d-none d-md-block">
           <h5>Sassy!</h5>
          </div>
         </div>

        <div class="item">
         <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/t4bc0d3/image/upload/c_scale,h_1868/v1497010440/Images/Mom_1995.jpg" class="photo d-block img-fluid" alt="Picture of Sandra at 51">
          <div class="carousel-caption cap2 d-none d-md-block">
           <h5>Beautiful Bride</h5>
          </div>
         </div>

        <div class="item">
         <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/t4bc0d3/image/upload/v1497010463/Images/Mom_at_Cottage.jpg" class="photo d-block img-fluid" alt="Picture of Sandra at 68">
          <div class="carousel-caption cap3 d-none d-md-block">
           <h5>Creating...Something</h5>
          </div>                                  
         </div>
        </div>

     <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
       <span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href-target="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
       <span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
      </div>
     </div>
```

here is the css pertaining to the carousel:

```
 #myCarousel {
   width: 35%;
   height: 35%;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

Comment: your question is not clear - what do you mean by my page jumps ?.. can you please reframe your question?

Comment: My apologies, if you scroll down below the carousel the page will jump to the top when the second pic scrolls to the third and then again when the third scrolls back to the first.

Comment: It's working as expected- I scrolled down the page and the pics are scrolling automatically without any issues

Comment: Hmmm I wonder if it's only a glitch when I'm in work mode.

Comment: Nope, it still does it. Not sure why it's working for you. If I scroll down the page to read the stories, it will jump to the top of the page as the carousel changes. Very frustrating. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Yup, I took it out of the page :) I have used a carousel since on another page and had no issue. I feel it might have been a glitch of codepen. Probably not very helpful to you unfortunately